# Angular form do not get submitted when dynamically adding row

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to develop a page with a total of 6 input fields - 2 constant and 4 dynamic. A single form needs to send data with dynamic marks rows that will be added by users choice.

#### View :

```
<body ng-controller="homeController">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
<h3>Students Form</h3>
<form name="StudentForm">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.regno" placeholder="Reg Number">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.name" placeholder="Student Name">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showMarks" ng-repeat="formData in studentMarks">
      <div class="row">
      <br>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subone"   
        placeholder="Subject 1" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subtwo"     
        placeholder="Subject 2" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subthree" 
        placeholder="Subject 3" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subfour" 
        placeholder="Subject 4" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><button ng-click="delMarks()"> Delete</button></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button ng-model="addBtnMarks" ng-click="addMarks(addBtnMarks)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button ng-click="editEnquiry()"> Edit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="saveFullForm()"> Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button onclick="window.print()"> Print</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</body>
```

#### Controller :

```
var std = angular.module("studentsApp",[]);
std.controller("homeController", function($scope){
$scope.showMarks=false;
$scope.studentMarks=[];

$scope.addMarks = function (){
$scope.showMarks=true;
var rowConut = $scope.studentMarks.length +1;
$scope.studentMarks.push({
subone:0,
subtwo:0,
subthree:0,
subfour:0,

});
console.log(rowConut);
console.log($scope.studentMarks);
};

$scope.delMarks = function (){
rowConut = $scope.studentMarks.length -1;
$scope.studentMarks.pop();
console.log(rowConut);
console.log($scope.studentMarks);
};

$scope.saveFullForm = function(){
//

console.log($scope.formData);
console.log($scope.marks);
console.log($scope.studentMarks);
};
});
```

#### Problem is:

> When I click -save button form data for dynamic rows does not get shown up 
>   in the console. Also, when adding more than one row, -delete button does 
>   not deletes individual rows. The last row gets deleted by default. What might be the
>   problem in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When using array.pop, it will remove the last element in the array. The solution is to pass the element index from the view through ng-click and splice the array based on the index , thus the element will be remove out from the array

**View**

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><button ng-click="delMarks($index)"> Delete</button></div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.delMarks = function (index){
   rowConut = $scope.studentMarks.length -1;
   $scope.studentMarks.splice(index,1);
   console.log(rowConut);
   console.log($scope.studentMarks);
};
```

**Update**

```js
var std = angular.module("studentsApp",[]);
std.controller("homeController", function($scope){
$scope.showMarks=false;
$scope.studentMarks=[];

$scope.addMarks = function (){
$scope.showMarks=true;
var rowConut = $scope.studentMarks.length +1;
$scope.studentMarks.push({
subone:$scope.formData.regno,
subtwo:0,
subthree:0,
subfour:0,

});
//console.log(rowConut);
//console.log($scope.studentMarks);
};

$scope.delMarks = function (index){
rowConut = $scope.studentMarks.length -1;
$scope.studentMarks.splice(index,1);
//$scope.studentMarks.pop();
//console.log(rowConut);
//console.log($scope.studentMarks);
};

$scope.saveFullForm = function(){
//

console.log($scope.formData);
console.log($scope.marks);
console.log($scope.studentMarks);
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="studentsApp">
<body ng-controller="homeController">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
<h3>Students Form</h3>
<form name="StudentForm">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.regno" placeholder="Reg Number">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.name" placeholder="Student Name">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showMarks" ng-repeat="formData in studentMarks">
      <div class="row">
      <br>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subone"   
        placeholder="Subject 1" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subtwo"     
        placeholder="Subject 2" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subthree" 
        placeholder="Subject 3" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.subfour" 
        placeholder="Subject 4" style="width:70%"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><button ng-click="delMarks($index)"> Delete</button></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button ng-model="addBtnMarks" ng-click="addMarks()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button ng-click="editEnquiry()"> Edit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="saveFullForm()"> Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button onclick="window.print()"> Print</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not working. If we are adding 3 rows and deleting the second row, third also also gets deleted and data of 2nd gets copied to first after deletion.

Comment: And after adding a row it does not gets deleted.

Comment: Hi @NoobOwl, sorry my mistake. It should be  just $scope.studentMarks.splice not $scope.studentMarks = $scope.studentMarks.splice. Please refer to updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the update @digit. One more thing, how can these data be edited when clicking edit button if the input elements are diabled. Or gets saved with save button.

Comment: Do you mean that user cannot key in the input text?